# Symfony form ckeditor phpunit

Tags: symfony, phpunit

Проблема в тестировании формы, сама форма если в ней сменить поля с CKEDITOR::class на textType тест проходит.. Если остается ckeditor то ловлю ошибку :

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType::__construct() must be an instance of Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Model\ConfigManagerInterface, none given
```

Сам тест:

```
public function testSubmitValidData()
{
    $form = $this->factory->create(NewsTranslationType::class);

    $formData = [
        'title' => 'News title',
        'shortDescription' => 'Short description',
        'description' => 'Description',
    ];

    // submit the data to the form directly
    $form->submit($formData);

    $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());

    $view = $form->createView();
    $children = $view->children;

    foreach (array_keys($formData) as $key) {
        $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
    }
}
```

И форма

```
$builder->add(
        'title',
        TextType::class,
        [
            'constraints' => [
                new Length(['max' => 50]),
                new NotBlank(),
            ],
            'label' => 'common.title',
            'attr' =>
                ['placeholder' => 'common.title'],
        ]
    )
    ->add(
        'shortDescription',
        CKEditorType::class,
        [
            'constraints' => [
                new Length(['max' => 200]),
                new NotBlank(),
            ],
            'label' => 'common.short_description',
            'attr' =>
                ['placeholder' => 'common.short_description', 'class' => 'tinymce'],
        ]
    )
    ->add(
        'description',
        CKEditorType::class,
        [
            'constraints' => [
                new Length(['max' => 1000]),
                new NotBlank(),
            ],
            'label' => 'common.description',
            'attr' =>
                ['placeholder' => 'common.description'],
        ]
    );
```

Пробую делать как-то так всё таже ошибка.

```
/**
 * Load the ValidatorExtension so RepeatedType can resolve 'invalid_message'
 * @return array
 */
protected function getExtensions()
{
    return [new ValidatorExtension(Validation::createValidator()),
        new PreloadedExtension(
            [
                new NewsTranslationType(),
            ],
            [new CKEditorType(new ConfigManager(), new PluginManager(), new StylesSetManager(), new TemplateManager(), new ToolbarManager())]
        ),
    ];
}
```

Comment: Если делать по этой [инструкции](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/installation.html) , должно все работать. И [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674390/using-ckeditor-in-symfony3) такой же вопрос решался.

Comment: Вы наверное не правильно меня поняли, у меня форма работает отлично, я пытаюсь написать тест для неё, но не знаю как добавить extension этого едитора.. Потому как если я меняю в форме поля на textType тест проходит...

Comment: Я правильно понял. А Вы ссылки смотрели?

Comment: Смотрел ссылки у меня всё так как в документации, прочитал все коментарии там выполнив консольные команды у меня всё в принципе так как там все сервисы и.т.д едитора... Дело в том что у меня только в тесте проблема такая, страница загружается всё ок и едитор грузит

Comment: Если вы понимаете в чём проблема, обьясните пожайлуста